# Remove vim manually after checkinstall

Tags: vim, uninstall

I downloaded this Vim [release](https://github.com/vim/vim/releases/tag/v8.0.0326) and extract the tarball on Ubuntu 16.04. Then I switched to the vim directory and run `sudo checkinstall`, the procedure ends up with:

```
Makefile:2412: recipe for target 'installpack' failed
make[1]: *** [installpack] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/mudde/Downloads/vim-8.0.0326/src'
Makefile:36: recipe for target 'install' failed
make: *** [install] Error 2

****  Installation failed. Aborting package creation.

Restoring overwritten files from backup...OK

Cleaning up...OK

Bye.
```

It mentioned there are errors, but I can start `/usr/local/bin/vim`.

```
vim --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.0 (2016 Sep 12, compiled Feb 12 2017 19:18:51)
Included patches: 1-326
```

Now I want to remove it, but using package manager does not work

```
sudo apt-get remove vim
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'vim' is not installed, so not removed
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  feh libexif12 libjpeg-progs libjpeg9 linux-headers-4.4.0-57 linux-headers-4.4.0-57-generic
  linux-image-4.4.0-57-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-57-generic lua-lgi menu rlwrap
  vim-gui-common vim-runtime
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 62 not upgraded.
```

How to remove vim manually? Can I delete all files and directories or should I exclude some or at the other hand did I missed something?

```
$ sudo find /etc /usr /lib /var -name "*vim*" -prune
/etc/vim
/usr/share/man/man5/apparmor.vim.5.gz
/usr/share/man/man5/vim-registry.5.gz
/usr/share/man/it/man1/vimdiff.1.gz
/usr/share/man/it/man1/vim.1.gz
/usr/share/man/it/man1/rvim.1.gz
/usr/share/man/it/man1/gvim.1.gz
/usr/share/man/it/man1/gvimtutor.1.gz
/usr/share/man/it/man1/evim.1.gz
/usr/share/man/it/man1/gvimdiff.1.gz
/usr/share/man/it/man1/rgvim.1.gz
/usr/share/man/it/man1/vimtutor.1.gz
/usr/share/man/fr/man1/vimdiff.1.gz
/usr/share/man/fr/man1/vim.1.gz
/usr/share/man/fr/man1/rvim.1.gz
/usr/share/man/fr/man1/gvim.1.gz
/usr/share/man/fr/man1/gvimtutor.1.gz
/usr/share/man/fr/man1/evim.1.gz
/usr/share/man/fr/man1/gvimdiff.1.gz
/usr/share/man/fr/man1/rgvim.1.gz
/usr/share/man/fr/man1/vimtutor.1.gz
/usr/share/man/pl/man1/vimdiff.1.gz
/usr/share/man/pl/man1/vim.1.gz
/usr/share/man/pl/man1/rvim.1.gz
/usr/share/man/pl/man1/gvim.1.gz
/usr/share/man/pl/man1/gvimtutor.1.gz
/usr/share/man/pl/man1/evim.1.gz
/usr/share/man/pl/man1/gvimdiff.1.gz
/usr/share/man/pl/man1/rgvim.1.gz
/usr/share/man/pl/man1/vimtutor.1.gz
/usr/share/man/ru/man1/vimdiff.1.gz
/usr/share/man/ru/man1/vim.1.gz
/usr/share/man/ru/man1/rvim.1.gz
/usr/share/man/ru/man1/gvim.1.gz
/usr/share/man/ru/man1/gvimtutor.1.gz
/usr/share/man/ru/man1/evim.1.gz
/usr/share/man/ru/man1/gvimdiff.1.gz
/usr/share/man/ru/man1/rgvim.1.gz
/usr/share/man/ru/man1/vimtutor.1.gz
/usr/share/man/ja/man1/vimdiff.1.gz
/usr/share/man/ja/man1/vim.1.gz
/usr/share/man/ja/man1/rvim.1.gz
/usr/share/man/ja/man1/gvim.1.gz
/usr/share/man/ja/man1/gvimtutor.1.gz
/usr/share/man/ja/man1/evim.1.gz
/usr/share/man/ja/man1/gvimdiff.1.gz
/usr/share/man/ja/man1/rgvim.1.gz
/usr/share/man/ja/man1/vimtutor.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/vimdiff.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/vim.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/rvim.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/vim-addon-manager.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/vim-addons.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/vimdot.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/gvim.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/gvimtutor.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/evim.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/gvimdiff.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/rgvim.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/vimtutor.1.gz
/usr/share/lintian/overrides/vim-common
/usr/share/lintian/overrides/vim-gui-common
/usr/share/doc/vim-common
/usr/share/doc/vim-addon-manager
/usr/share/doc/vim-gui-common
/usr/share/doc/vim-runtime
/usr/share/doc/mercurial-common/examples/vim
/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/vim-addon-manager
/usr/share/pixmaps/vim-32.xpm
/usr/share/pixmaps/vim-16.xpm
/usr/share/pixmaps/vim-48.xpm
/usr/share/pixmaps/gvim.svg
/usr/share/applications/vim.desktop
/usr/share/applications/gvim.desktop
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/48x48/apps/gvim.png
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/apps/gvim.svg
/usr/share/icons/locolor/32x32/apps/gvim.png
/usr/share/icons/locolor/16x16/apps/gvim.png
/usr/share/vim
/usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/specifications/vim-addon-manager-0.5.3.gemspec
/usr/share/cmake-3.5/editors/vim
/usr/share/gettext/styles/po-vim.css
/usr/bin/vim-addon-manager
/usr/bin/vim-addons
/usr/bin/vimdot
/usr/bin/gvimtutor
/usr/bin/vimtutor
/usr/lib/mime/packages/vim-common
/usr/lib/mime/packages/vim-gui-common
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vim
/usr/lib/git-core/mergetools/vimdiff2
/usr/lib/git-core/mergetools/vimdiff
/usr/lib/git-core/mergetools/vimdiff3
/usr/lib/git-core/mergetools/gvimdiff
/usr/lib/git-core/mergetools/gvimdiff2
/usr/lib/git-core/mergetools/gvimdiff3
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-57-generic/include/config/video/vim2m.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-59-generic/include/config/video/vim2m.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-62-generic/include/config/video/vim2m.h
/usr/local/share/awesome/lib/awful/hotkeys_popup/keys/vim.lua
/usr/local/share/man/man1/vim.1
/usr/local/share/man/man1/vimtutor.1
/usr/local/share/man/man1/vimdiff.1
/usr/local/share/man/man1/evim.1
/usr/local/share/doc/awesome/doc/libraries/awful.hotkeys_popup.keys.vim.html
/usr/local/share/vim
/usr/local/bin/vim
/usr/local/bin/vim.rm
/usr/local/bin/vimtutor
/lib/modules/4.4.0-57-generic/kernel/drivers/media/platform/vim2m.ko
/lib/modules/4.4.0-59-generic/kernel/drivers/media/platform/vim2m.ko
/lib/modules/4.4.0-62-generic/kernel/drivers/media/platform/vim2m.ko
/var/lib/dpkg/info/vim-common.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/vim-common.conffiles
/var/lib/dpkg/info/vim-common.preinst
/var/lib/dpkg/info/vim-common.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/vim-addon-manager.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/vim-addon-manager.prerm
/var/lib/dpkg/info/vim-addon-manager.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/vim-addon-manager.preinst
/var/lib/dpkg/info/vim-addon-manager.postinst
/var/lib/dpkg/info/vim-addon-manager.postrm
/var/lib/dpkg/info/vim-latexsuite.postrm
/var/lib/dpkg/info/vim-latexsuite.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/vim-gui-common.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/vim-gui-common.conffiles
/var/lib/dpkg/info/vim-gui-common.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/vim-runtime.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/vim-runtime.postrm
/var/lib/dpkg/info/vim-runtime.postinst
/var/lib/dpkg/info/vim-runtime.preinst
/var/lib/dpkg/info/vim-runtime.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/vim-tiny.list
/var/lib/vim
/var/cache/apt/archives/vim-runtime_2%3a7.4.1689-3ubuntu1.2_all.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/vim_2%3a7.4.1689-3ubuntu1.2_amd64.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/vim-addon-manager_0.5.5_all.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/vim-latexsuite_20141116.812-2_all.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/vim-gui-common_2%3a7.4.1689-3ubuntu1.2_all.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/vim-gtk_2%3a7.4.1689-3ubuntu1.2_amd64.deb
```

Comment: @Kusalananda I used `checkinstall` but I can't remove it via package manager like `apt`.

Comment: `checkinstall` seems to have failed (first log in your question). This probably means that it never created a package for you and instead left the files in place.

Comment: @Kusalananda The error message shows at first "installpack failed" and secondly "make install failed" but the vim was installed under `/usr/local/*` as I mentioned in my question.

Comment: Yes. You have a partial installation of `vim` from a failed `make install`. `checkinstall` never managed to do its job because `make install` failed, so you have a partial installation. Some files are probably missing, others are not.

Comment: @Kusalananda With respect to my question, which files and directories should I remove?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`checkinstall` is [the Debian way](https://wiki.debian.org/CheckInstall) to make the Debian package manager aware of packages that you can build through `configure` and `make && make install`. Apparently something went wrong during installation via `checkinstall` and the your build is not properly registered as installed package.

You may uninstall the software in several ways. Some packages provide the target `uninstall` (i.e. `make uninstall`). If not, you have to remove the according files by hand. Using `find` and searching for a suitable `-mtime` or `-mmin` might be most promising. If not, you may install vim into a temporary base directory and use the result as a pattern to search for files to delete.

Answer (score 1):

You did not install vim via the package manager, so you won't be able to uninstall it that way. Looking in `/usr/local` will make it simple for you, as `vim` does not install a lot of files.

Comment: But [here](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe/wiki/Building-Vim-from-source) they mention using `checkinstall` which stated that "If you want to be able to easily uninstall vim use"? That implies you can use package manager, I guess. And I think there are some more files and directories related, not only `/usr/local`.